# PDF report generating in php

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I have a php file which generate pdf report of guest reviews from the table. It shows well. But problem is in the report , Review cell content shows in a single line. Not breaks it. Please help me to break the line in review cell in a suitable point.

[image]

**Here is the code.**

```
        include("connect.php");

        $SQL = "SELECT * FROM reviews  ";
        $run=mysql_query($SQL,$con) or die ("SQL error");


    //---------------------pdf creation-------------------------------------------
require("fpdf/fpdf.php");
$pdf=new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont("Arial","B",10);
$pdf->Cell(190,10,"Guest reviews report",1,1,'C');
$pdf->SetFont("Arial","B",10);
$pdf->Cell(20,10,"Booking ID",1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(40,10,"Guest name",1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(50,10,"email",1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(60,10,"Review",1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(20,10,"Rate",1,1,'C');

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($run))
{

$pdf->SetFont("Arial","B",10);

        $pdf->Cell(20,10,$row['bookingid'],1,0);
        $pdf->Cell(40,10,$row['name'],1,0);
        $pdf->Cell(50,10,$row['email'],1,0);
        $pdf->Cell(60,10,$row['review'],1,0);
        $pdf->Cell(20,10,$row['rating'],1,1);       

}

$pdf->Output(); 

?>
```

I have included a screenshot of my report.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmuhW.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **MultiCell**. Here is the example

```
$pdf->MultiCell(55, 5, $row['review'], 1, 'L', 1, 0, '', '', true);
```

And here is the example from the **tcpdf**: https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_005/

Documentation about MultiCell: http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/multicell.htm

Note: `55` is the width and `5` is the height. In your case they would be `60` and `10`

> MultiCell(float w, float h, string txt [, mixed border [, string align [, boolean fill]]])

Comment: It gives a black cell

Comment: Just try to adjust it to your source.